How to Implement a Go slog Handler for Incremental Step Logging
I'm trying to implement a Go slog handler that automatically increments and logs step numbers when invoked. The handler should support multiple nested levels managed by the user, but it only needs to support single-threaded usage.
Intended usage (the exact implementation can vary):
handler := NewSteppedHandler()
logger := slog.New(handler)
logger.Info("Log message") // STEP 1) Log message
handler.PushLevel()
logger.Info("Log message") // STEP 2.1) Log message
logger.Info("Log message") // STEP: 2.2) Log message
handler.PushLevel()
logger.Info("Log message") // STEP 2.3.1) Log message
logger.Info("Log message") // STEP 2.3.2) Log message
handler.PopLevel()
logger.Info("Log message") // STEP 2.4) Log message
handler.PopLevel()
logger.Info("Log message") // STEP: 3) Log message

Current design:
type SteppedHandler struct {
    h  slog.Handler
    mu sync.Mutex
    steps         []int  // [1, 2, 3] -> STEP 1.2.3)
}

Issues with the current design:
Calling logger.With or logger.WithGroup results in a new (duplicated) SteppedHandler which is out of the user's control:
handler := NewSteppedHandler()
logger := slog.New(handler)
newLogger := logger.With(...)
// The user is unable to do newHandler.PushLevel() because there isn't a newHandler at disposal.
// Accessing the handler via newLogger.Handler().(*SteppedHandler) is possible but not elegant...

We could let the duplicated SteppedHandler share the steps slice with the original one by making this field a *[]int:
type SteppedHandler struct {
        ...
    steps         *[]int
}

However, this approach is problematic because manipulating steps with handler.PushLevel() or handler.PopLevel() changes the state for both handlers, which I believe is not how a slog handler should be used.
Question: How can I achieve this functionality in an elegant way?

Hi, I lack experience with log, can you tell me the purpose of the With/WithGroup function?
